# How to get a list of staked assets by address

Tags: solidity

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out.

I have the following public mapping:

```
mapping(uint256 => address) public staked;
```

When I stake an assets, I assign it like so:

```
function stake(uint256[] memory tokenIds) external {
    //forloop
    staked[tokenIds[i]] = msg.sender;
}
```

I know I can call `contract.staked(1)` to get the person who staked it, but how would I get an array back of every asset id staked by 1 address? Hoping to make this a public call.

Answer (score 0):

> *but how would I get an array back of every asset id staked by 1 address*

You'll need to duplicate the data in a second mapping. The value can be an array containing all token IDs staked by an address.

```
mapping(uint256 => address) public staked;
mapping(address => uint256[]) stakedByAdddress;

function stake(uint256[] memory tokenIds) external {
    staked[tokenIds[i]] = msg.sender;
    stakedByAdddress[msg.sender].push(tokenIds[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, guess that wouldn't be too bad. But makes withdrawing a lot more costly on gas to remove

Comment: @bryan Yes, that's a drawback of this approach. If you're expecting users to unstake often or use larger amount of `tokenIds`, you could also use an [iterable mapping](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/iterable-mapping/) as the value. I.e. `stakedByAdddress` would become a nested mapping.